# Solving eigen on GPU - CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, eigen

I recently write a C++ program using **eigen**. But I found that my poor CPI cannot handle the large computation load. I estimate it demands at least a day of computation and I am short of time, especially since I may need debugging time too. I'm considering using GPU acceleration, but I don't know how to adapt my code for CUDA (or some other platforms, but I prefer CUDA).

Are there any convenient methods to apply GPU acceleration on eigen program?

Comment: Are you using dense or sparse matrixes? sparse solvers are quite fast comparing to dense solvers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cuSolver` is a linar algebra library  by **NVIDIA**. It provides fast and  efficient  eigen solver among tons of other linear algebra facilities.
You might also want to take a look at the SDK examples (7_Libraries).

[Here's the link to the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#introduction).

Other useful libraries are

- MAGMA - https://developer.nvidia.com/magma
- CULA - http://www.culatools.com/